# os.path.abspath ignoring last directory

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to generate a CSV file for data migration and I am using the following code to generate the filename along with path

```
log_file = os.path.abspath(
        "./app/static/logs/") + 'migration_log_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M%S") + '.csv'
```

This gives the file name as

`C:My-Source-Code-Root\app\static\logsmigration_log_03022020131829.csv`

but I need this file inside `logs` folder so the complete name should be

`C:My-Source-Code-Root\app\static\logs\migration_log_03022020131829.csv`.

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
log_file = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('./app/static/logs/'),'migration_log_'+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M%S") + '.csv')
```